# Not able to change image "onhover" in my menu bar?

Tags: html, css, facebook

i have to create a menu bar in which there is notification globe like facebook.
i am getting issue of not changing image on hover like facebook does.
so shall i get some appropriate solution??
my code is below:

```
#noti_Container {
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/globe-final_simple.png) no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
}

#noti_container:onhover{
    background:url(../images/globe-final_onhover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the globe onhover instead of this i want dark color globe.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you fire that functions? Please indicate the code

Answer (score 2):

```
#noti_container:hover{
background:url(../images/globe-final_onhover.png) no-repeat;}
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spelling mistake. you used small "c" instead of "C". Also there is no `onhover`. you have to use `hover`. Update your CSS like below.

```
#noti_Container:hover{
background:url(../images/globe-final_onhover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it had helped me in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> `#noti_container:hover{
>   background:url(../images/globe-final_onhover.png) no-repeat !important;}`